# GMap.NET проблемы с отображением маркеров

Tags: c#, google-maps

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так делаю. Если задаю маркер с прописанными вручную координатами, он отображается на карте, а если получаю из БД, ничего не отображается. И не имеет значения, сколько маркеров создается, один или много.

```
GMapOverlay markers=new GMapOverlay("markers");
DateTime dnow = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-30);

System.Data.DataTable dt = cb.GetData(dnow);
Bitmap imag = Bitmap.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\marker_red.png") as Bitmap;

//for (int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
//{
    double lat = double.Parse(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1].ToString());
    double lng = double.Parse(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[2].ToString());
    GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle mar = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(49.9920, 36.23122), imag);
    //GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle markerG = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(lat, lng), imag); 
    markers.Markers.Add(mar);
 //}
 gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markers);
```

Comment: А можете посмотреть в отладчике что у вас в перенных lat и lng получается после double.Parse и сообщить нам?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос снят. Проблема в некорректных данных из БД.

Comment: Так удалите вопрос, раз причина никак не связана с исходными данными в вопрос.